Moving existing Database to Entity Framework Core, initial migration fails because tables already exist
I am updating an existing desktop code base (to .NET 8.0) and it's backing database with more than 50 tables to use Entity Framework Core 8.0 (EFC from here on out); previously we managed database updates and changes without the help of a framework (did not use the older Entity Framework). I have set up the initial create (Add-Migration InitialCreate), which generated a several thousand line file for both the up and down migration. However, when I run Update-Database it fails on the first table because it already exists. I would like to be able to use the generated file for both existing users on our next update, and for new users who do not have any databases from the previous version. How can I add in a check to the InitialCreate migration so that it doesn't throw an exception if the table already exists?
I have already discovered that EFC would allow us to write the raw sql to create each of these tables, but this seems to largely defeat the purpose of moving over to EFC and would take much more time to write than if we can get the generated file to simply check if the database already exists. I have also found suggestions to just make an empty initial migration but that will leave new users without the needed tables.
We are using .NET 8.0 and EFC 8.0.
What I've tried and found so far:
I've found some stack overflow posts that indicate that this was possible back in Entity Framework, but not anything useful for Entity Framework Core. I have also found blog posts suggesting that we just write the raw sql for this first migration, which gives access to the EXISTS sql operator, but this will be very tedious and take several thousands of lines of code, and largely defeats the purpose of moving to a framework to handle these sql migrations for us. I have also checked to make sure that we are not calling EnsureCreated() as several of the linked SO questions are about.

It's not a 100% match on what you have asked for, but you can make 2 InitialCreate migrations.  The one you have works for new users that do not have any database.  The second, add the -IgnoreChanges flag.  This will create a migration beginning with your current context(should match your current db).

Hey Kevin, thanks for the idea. I guess I'm still left with the same question of how do I determine which migration to use? If I could tell that the database already exists, I could easily skip the entire migration with an if statement without needing two copies of the same migration (one empty one with all the creates).

You still will want both migrations, as they will create the migration history table.  Then you would want to wrap the whole thing in a couple of checks - check for migration history table, and if exists, any migrations in it.  if not found, check if database exists, run correct initial create.  If found, only apply necessary migrations to bring up-to-date.  EFC has context.Database.CanConnect() to check if db exists and context.HasMigrationBeenApplied() and GetAppliedMigrations() for use in applying migration patches

Our solution is to push an update in the previous version of our desktop application to contain the backing __EFMigrationsHistory table and the first migration row, that way when existing customers update Entity Framework Core skips the initial creation.
